# Angular show a modal in a nested component

Tags: angular, bootstrap-modal

all.

I have a component which controls adding a new record. The adding of the record is handled by a form inside a modal. I'd like to click a button which would then open the modal and elicit the data from the user. When they click a "save" button inside the modal, that component would manage sending the data to the backend via a service.

The method I chose was to include the directive for the record-adding component into the HTML for app.component:

```
<div id="list">
  <div style="padding-bottom: 1em">
    <h2>List of Events:</h2>
  </div>

  <app-calendar></app-calendar>

  <p style="margin-top: 20px"><button class="btn btn-primary" data-model="modal" data-target="#exampleModal">Add Event</button></p>
</div>

<div id="details">
    <add-event></add-event>
</div>
```

App-calendar fetches events and displays them in a list-group. This works fine. The add-event component has the sample modal code from getbootstrap in it's template:

```
<div class="modal fade" id="exampleModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Modal title</h5>
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
          <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        ...
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Problem is, clicking the button does nothing, and there are no errors in the console. What am I missing? My expectation was that using the ID property I should be able to interact with the add-event template. Do I need to import the add-event component and then send it a message to show the modal instead? What would that look like? I tried binding [hidden] to a property in add-event, and bound the (click) event on the button to calling a function in add-event which changed the property from true to false, but that didn't work either.

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'event-detail',
  templateUrl: './event-detail.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./event-detail.component.css']
})
export class EventDetailComponent {
  isHidden;

  constructor() {
    this.isHidden = true;
  };

  showDetailModal() {
    this.isHidden = false;
  };
}
```

In this case I set a template variable.

Comment: suggestion, why not use ngx-bootstrap/modal?

Comment: Hmm.. a) did not know it existed and b) bootstrap is our standard at work, but thanks.

Comment: ngx-bootstrap is based on bootstrap - 3.x and 4.x.  The lib adds programmatic access to the bootstrap components. Its better than using jQuery, or handrolling your own custom code imho